# QureyDsl: didn't create Q class with gradle in Eclipse [Spring 2.x]

Tags: spring, gradle, querydsl

There definitely seems to be a problem with build.gradle. but I didn't catch anything. I think I missed something. there's build.grable.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        queryDslVersion = '5.0.0'
    }
}

plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.18-SNAPSHOT'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

group = 'dev.chanwook.springstudy'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
  sourceCompatibility = '11'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
  maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':domain')

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    // junit
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    
    // Database
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    
    // lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    
    // Spring Security
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    
    // jjwt
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.12.3'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.3'
    runtimeOnly 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.12.3'
    
    // QueryDSL
    implementation "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}"
    annotationProcessor(
            "javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api",
            "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api",
            "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}:jpa")
            
    // swagger
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.12'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

What's interesting is that when I open this project in vscode, the Q class is generated normally. but I want in Eclipse. plaese comment for this problem. thack you.